# cargo install racer - compiler errors

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to [install racer](https://github.com/racer-rust/racer#with-cargo-install) using cargo install:

```sh
cargo +nightly install racer
```

And at some point it fails with these errors:

```sh
   Compiling racer v2.2.2
error[E0053]: method `fallback_fluent_bundle` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> /home/username/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/racer-2.2.2/src/racer/ast.rs:36:41
   |
36 |     fn fallback_fluent_bundle(&self) -> &Lrc<rustc_errors::FluentBundle> {
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                         |
   |                                         expected struct `fluent_bundle::bundle::FluentBundle`, found struct `Lrc`
   |                                         help: change the output type to match the trait: `&fluent_bundle::bundle::FluentBundle<fluent_bundle::resource::FluentResource, intl_memoizer::IntlLangMemoizer>`
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(&DummyEmitter) -> &fluent_bundle::bundle::FluentBundle<fluent_bundle::resource::FluentResource, intl_memoizer::IntlLangMemoizer>`
              found fn pointer `fn(&DummyEmitter) -> &Lrc<fluent_bundle::bundle::FluentBundle<fluent_bundle::resource::FluentResource, intl_memoizer::IntlLangMemoizer>>`

error[E0023]: this pattern has 5 fields, but the corresponding tuple variant has 6 fields
   --> /home/username/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/racer-2.2.2/src/racer/ast.rs:232:31
    |
232 |             visit::FnKind::Fn(_, _, ref fn_sig, _, _) => &*fn_sig.decl,
    |                               ^  ^  ^^^^^^^^^^  ^  ^ expected 6 fields, found 5
    |
help: use `_` to explicitly ignore each field
    |
232 |             visit::FnKind::Fn(_, _, ref fn_sig, _, _, _) => &*fn_sig.decl,
    |                                                     +++


Some errors have detailed explanations: E0023, E0053, E0277.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0023`.
error: could not compile `racer` due to 7 previous errors
```

How to fix it? What's causing it?

```
rustc --version                                                                                                                                                                            
rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)

cargo --version                                                                                                                                                                            
cargo 1.63.0 (fd9c4297c 2022-07-01)

echo $RUST_SRC_PATH                                                              
/home/username/.cargo/bin
```

Comment: https://github.com/racer-rust/racer/issues/1181